# Error message: "This kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu"

Tags: kernel, 64-bit

I have already activated the `AMD Virtualization` option in the BIOS, but I continue to see the error. My processor is 64-bit compatible.

PS.: Hi, i want to tell everyone that i found my mistake. I am installing it in Virtual Box and i was selected Ubuntu instead of Ubuntu 64 bit. It seems stupid but this selection is hiiden. Have a nice day.

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: To use 64 bit computing you need three things: 1) A CPU capable of 64 bit mode. (Check [here](http://products.amd.com/pages/)).  2) A BIOS allowing you to enable that.  3) an OS using it. -- It sounds as if you have 3, 2 is unsure and 1 can only be answered after you add your CPU model to the post. Most (if not all) modern AMD CPU's do support amd64 though.